How to ensure that the output of my generative model is uniform?
Generative models transform noise to data. However, is there a way to ensure the output of my generative model follows a specific distribution, say uniform?
More concretely, applying a scalar function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ to the output of my generative model $G(z)\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is there a way to ensure that $f(G(z))$ is uniform in an interval [a,b]?
EDIT: f is a fixed function that cannot be changed. Hence, I am looking for some ways to regularize the parameters of $G$ such that $f\circ G$ is uniform.

You are saying that when you train your generative model
you want $f(G(z))$ to be (at least part of) the loss function.
Then training will take care of the rest.

well, yes, but how to ensure uniformity is the question

Show us the training code for your G function (maybe it's an autoencoder) and for the loss function you're using. What non-uniform result is it producing?

Thanks for your interest. However, I think my question is well-defined as it is stated now. If my question is unclear, I am happy to elaborate. I don't understand what you even mean by "What non-uniform result is it producing?" Take any function mapping from the data space to $R$. It will very likely be not uniform.

When I take some simple mapping from the data space to $R$, for example a function that draws a random value in $[a, b]$, the result for the most part is pretty uniform. One could choose a different function, when accompanied by some business use case justification. I understand that you feel your question of a few days ago is perfect as-is, and will garner many answers of utility to you and to the general readership. Therefore I won't offer any additional reprex suggestions to you.

I see where the confusion come from. $f$ in my case is a fixed function, we cannot change it and it is not a random variable. Hence, I am looking for some ways to regularize the parameters of $G$ such that $f\circ G$ is uniform. Any idea?
